# Issue with ODBC connection

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

I have an issue with an ASP page that I have which needs to connect to a Database located in my own computer.

I have this:

```
    Set con = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DSN = "DSN=STGI_Ajedrez"
con.Open DSN, 1
```

but I dont know how to properly configure the DSN since I dont know the path to my database. It is in my own computer and Im using "HeidiSQL" as manager. I've seen some tutorials to connect it to an SQL Server but I dont have it, as I said it is in my own computer and when Im adding a new DSN I dont know which one I have to choose (.txt,.mdb,.dbf,.db, etc.) and where to find it.

I know it may be a stupid question but I've been trying for a whole day and I couldnt solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to connect without using a DSN this page might be helpful
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to MySQL using ODBC you need to install the [ODBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). Only then will you get MySQL as option.

[image]